# How to configure default colors in gradle?

Tags: gradle, color-scheme

How can you change permanently the default colors of `gradle` output?

With my background color, gradle output is difficult to read.

[image]

So I want to change the output color.

One blog claims it can be done:
http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Colourizing-console-output-td3073839.html

So I tried to put this in my `(home)\.gradle\gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.color.normal=YELLOW
org.gradle.color.info=YELLOW
org.gradle.color.identifier=YELLOW
and
systemProp.org.gradle.color.normal=YELLOW
systemProp.org.gradle.color.info=YELLOW
systemProp.org.gradle.color.identifier=YELLOW
```

It didn't help.  So I tried this in my `(home)\.gradle\init.gradle`:

```
initscript {
    System.setProperty('org.gradle.color.normal', 'WHITE')
    System.setProperty('org.gradle.color.identifier', 'WHITE')
    System.setProperty('org.gradle.color.info', 'WHITE')
}
```

It also didn't help.

So far, the only way I can remove the colors is to run gradle with

```
gradle -v --console plain
```

But I don't want to type that every time I run a command.  So I tried to make it permanent with:

```
set GRADLE_OPTS=--console plain
```

But when I do that gradle complains : `Unrecognized option: --console`.

So is there any way to make a permanent change in the output colors?

Two solutions so far: 1. `doskey gradle=gradle --console plain $*` and 2. `set TERM=dumb`.  I would like errors to remain red though.

Answer (score 1):

Adding org.gradle.console=plain to gradle.properties removed the colors for me.

Comment: Thanks.  In the meantime I have replaced my computer, my OS, and my gradle is now at verstion 5.  I don't experience the problem any more.  But it might help someone.